# Economic possibility to execute many workflow tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

so I have these Airflow DAGs which consists of several tasks. Basically each task executes some independent analysis steps against a given code snippet and finally it is decided if this snippet can be used from a regulatory point of view.

Each tasks - depending on the code snippet - is quite short (1-25 minutes at most) and mostly it boils down to executing some external analysis tool (open source and internally) and processing the output of this tool.

All this works quite nice on my development machine but since we are analyzing quite a lot of code snippets during working hours (~50 per hour) and none outside of working hours, I'd like to get all of this up and running somewhere in the cloud (I don't really care if on google cloud, aws or azure).

So my question is what would be an economic way of getting this up and running in the cloud? I thought about using google cloud composer and these google preemptible VMs (the ones that shut down randomly but are super cheap) but it seems that I can not use the PVMs together with cloud composer.

Since the various steps in the DAG are independent the PVMs would be IMO great - if during task execution they are shut down I just retry this one task on a different PVM.

Thank you

Comment: For the `AWS` front, you have [`lambda`s](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) at your disposal and [`AwsLambdaHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_lambda_hook.py) to work with them.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I thought about lambda as well but I did not know that I can "install" my own tools into lambda and then execute them. For example I'd need to execute cloc in lambda and get the results. Is this possible?

Comment: As for `..economic way of getting this up and running..` it takes just about 10 mins to set-up `Airflow` on a bare machine; it's as simple as `pip install apache-airflow[<list-of-extras>]` followed by launching of `scheduler` and `webserver` (assuming `LocalExecutor`)

Comment: Hi, yea it's not about the effort to setup airflow - its about the computing power to execute our DAGs about 50 times per hour.

Comment: I've never used `lambda`s so can't comment on dependencies problem. But then of course [`PythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/python_operator.py) lets you run absolutely anything and `Airflow` already has some examples of using [`AwsHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py) that employs `AWS`'s `python` `SDK`: [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

Comment: `..its about the computing power to execute our DAGs..` this is a legit worry. We use `Airflow` as **pure orchestrator** wherein it runs on a dedicated *persistent* machine and invokes actual computations on **remote systems**. The remote machines in question are *ephemeral*: create, run, destroy types; so scaling isn't difficult (just tweak configs to create *heftier* boxes). With this setting, we have run DAGs containing 1200+ tasks with the CPU of our `Airflow` box barely touching 15%. We didn't even feel the need to move to `CeleryExecutor` / `MesosExecutor` / `KubernetesExecutor`

Comment: @y2k-shubham thats very interesting and actually exactly what I want to do. What kind of remote machines are you using - internal system or these google preemptible-vms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189584/discussion-between-y2k-shubham-and-pinas).

Answer (score 0):

On Google Cloud, there are a few options for you.

1. Run self-managed Airflow on a Compute Engine VM
2. Run [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer)

The best option will be a mix of how much you want to spend and what features you need. Self-managed Airflow is a great option if you want to have very low cost (less than $100 per month) and are OK self-managing the VM and taking on the risk that the SLA from Google will only cover the VM, so if Airflow malfunctions, you're going to have to detect it and fix it.

The benefit of Composer is the fact that it's integrated so you get things like IAM, Stackdriver, WebUI proxying and so on. You will pay more for the service, however, since it's managed. Presently there is no way to run Composer with preemptible VMs.

Your use case sounds like it could run on a default size cluster on Cloud Composer, though.

It's worth noting that if you go self-managed, you also get the benefit that Google actively contributes to Airflow, so things like the operators should work against the current product APIs. Google also contributes fixes and new operators pretty regularly.